# Postfix: smtpd_helo_restrictions being executes multiple times with smtpd_delay_reject = yes

Tags: postfix-mta

What I am trying to achieve is to add the HELO/EHLO command to the email header, so I tried to utilize `smtpd_helo_restrictions` to make it happen. Although it works, but sometimes the same header is appended multiple times.

After looking through some articles, I understand that when the parameter `smtpd_delay_reject` is being set to yes, the evaluation of `smtpd_helo_restrictions` will be delayed to the RCPT TO stage. That explains why sometimes the header is appended multiple times as there are multiple RCPT TO so the `smtpd_helo_restrictions` is being evaluated multiple times.

Due to the design, the parameter `smtpd_delay_reject` has to be fixed to yes. So is there any ways I can append the EHLO/HELO command to the header only once even in scenarios where there are multiple RCPT TO in the message?